# How to use vuetify's v-img inside v-html

Tags: vuejs2, vuetify.js

I would like to use `<v-img>` of vuetify inside `v-html` to replace the standard `<img>`, i.e.

```html
<div v-html="'<v-img src="some_image_url" />'">
```

I understand that `v-html` is meant for only standard HTML component, and I would like to know if there is anyway to use a custom component (such as `<v-img>`) inside `v-html`.

Comment: I think the short answer is no. Any reason why you can't use a slot or child element instead?

Comment: The application is an editor where user can add <img> using standard html tag. I would like to convert the <img> to <v-img> to take advantages of some of it's feature such as preloading.

Answer (score 1):

The example below uses some cheap and cheerful RegExps to do the parsing, nothing I would use in production code. My focus was on how to avoid using `v-html` rather than finding a reliable way to parse out the `<img>` tags.

The key thing I'm trying to demonstrate is how you can parse the text into chunks and then iterate over the chunks in the template to create `v-img` components. I've used a dummy component for `v-img` but the principle would be exactly the same for the real thing.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  
  components: {
    vImg: {
      template: '<strong>[<slot/>]</strong>'
    }
  },
  
  data () {
    return {
      text: 'Something something <img src="somepath"> and <img src="otherpath">'
    }
  },
  
  computed: {
    chunks () {
      const re = /(<img\s[^>]*>)/g
      const text = this.text
      const parts = text.split(re).filter(part => part)

      return parts.map(part => {
        if (part.match(re)) {
          const matchSrc = part.match(/\ssrc="([^"]*)"/)
          
          return {
            src: matchSrc && matchSrc[1]
          }
        }
        
        return part
      })
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.10/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <template v-for="chunk in chunks">
    <template v-if="typeof chunk === 'string'">{{ chunk }}</template>
    <v-img v-else>{{ chunk.src }}</v-img>
  </template>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but as you mentioned, the code is hacky and not ready for production, which is also not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve it with `v-runtime-template`, which can be found here:

https://github.com/alexjoverm/v-runtime-template

Cheers!